# How to check if an email was sent from or originated from a specific plugin?

Tags: plugins, email

How to check if an email was sent from or originated from a specific plugin.

E.g. I have an SMTP plugin which sends all mail via SMTP however I would like to determine in the SMTP plugin. If an email originated from plugin x then the SMTP plugin would assign different "from" and "reply-to" headers as oppose to if it originated from plugin y

Comment: I don't fully understand - you have 2 SMTP plugins sending two different emails?

Comment: No. It's one smtp plugin which captures all WordPress mail and sends them via smtp. However the "from" and "reply-to" is hard coded in the smtp plugin. which causes all emails to have the same hard coded "reply-to"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way of knowing something x is orginated from some plugin x. If both plugins do not offer any administrative controls for setting from and reply to address, you might want to hack the plugin files code sending email.
if it is using wp_mail function to send email, you can pass your headers as below before wp_mail,

```
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail('test@test.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers);
```

or you can have filter for from address

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
function my_mail_from( $email )
{
    return 'myemail@mydomain.com';
}
wp_mail('test@test.com', 'subject', 'message');
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
```